# how to load page with editable grid view with it's data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, runtime

really i think it is very complicated i hope it is not
my goal like this but this windows app

[Image](http://s17.postimage.org/rqg42ht8v/dpng.png)

i have abutton to browse an images folder i want user when choose image folder 
my page load and appear agridview  in editable mode and show images data i loaded from folder
user can change every row(every image) data
and click save button to save all images in database
i don not know how can i do this
can anybody help me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used a fantastic jquery API called [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, I don't believe you need to have the GV in edit mode, you just need to include and upload control in each row.  That way a user can select a file for each row and on button click you can loop through the GV and upload the file (if selected).  As far as the GV setup, just bind as you normally would with an `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`.

```
foreach (GridViewRow g in myGV.Rows)
{
    FileUpload f = g.FindControl("myFileUpload") as FileUpload
    if (f.HasFile)
    {
        // upload file
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for replay but when uploading alot of images like 20 or 30 image this will be difficult to browse every image so i browse image folder and loop through it and load every image in one row

Comment: If you want to allow the user to select multiple images in the browse dialog, you will have to use Flash or another plugin.  Something like this... http://www.uploadify.com/